Fix rendering issue when converting jupyter notebooks to PDF?
I'm converting a jupyter notebook to PDF format but have issue with the rendering.
I try two methods. The first is webpdf conversion. The problem with this is long texts are truncated, instead of breaking to multiple lines, as seen below:

The second method is, I believe, pdf conversion via LaTex. This method can break long texts to multiple lines. However, the problem is it generates unwanted characters/symbols at the end of each line and the beginning of the new line, as seen below:

The first line of the long_string_docstring doesn't have those characters because I break a new line.
Is there a way to fix these problems? I'm good with either method.
